# Subfield query impact on object graphql

Tags: relationship, graphql

Let's say I have an User model with a relationship to its pictures. I'd like to to do something like that:

```
{
    users {
        rights(min: "admin") {
             id
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have **only admin users**: "I want all admin users with their rights"

The key is, can the query arguments for an inner field affect the whole results ? Or the parent results ?

For now I'm doing

```
{
    users(rightsMin: "admin") {
        rights {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: What type of result are you trying to get? It's not really clear from the question what you're trying to achieve with those queries.

Comment: Adding some more details

Comment: Another example would be: "I only want users having as a friend "John"". `{ users { friends(contaning: "John") { ... } }` would be cool, but I can not find a way to do it but with `{ users(containingFriend: "John") { friends { ... } }`

Comment: This is because the main goal of such an argument would be "take also the friends or an empty array" for exemple :/